# Windows couldn't shutdown, then It starts without aero

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, aero

Yesterday I turned off my pc which has Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. It didn't turn off so I forced it off as it was getting late. Now I turn it on to find out that stuff like windows aero didn't load. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot with Google Chrome as an example window... Notice how no Aero features are there and how it's like Windows Classic]

Oh, and for those who will tell me to just switch themes:

[image: Theme Selection Window]

I tried troubleshooting it, but we all know nothing good ever comes out.
Also, when I tried shutting it down today, it wouldn't.. It would just remove the GUI leaving only the desktop background and mouse pointer.

I've tried rebooting in safe mode, still the same (when I reboot from safe mode to normal mode)

I've also tried using a Windows Repair Disk... but the Startup repair utility didn't work, and the closest system restore point is at 13th September 2013, which is a bit far away considering that this problem began last night.

Thanks to anyone who will post helpful answers

Edit: I've changed my theme to Windows Classic, and now it's shutting down OK. I've also just run the Aero Troubleshooter again, to be able to post the results in case it might help, so here it is:

[image: Page 1 of Report]
[image: Page 2 of Report]
[image: Page 3 of Report]

Comment: It seems like an issue with your Graphic Driver, try re-installing that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Does this affect the shutting down part though?

Comment: After shutting down part has nothing to do with the OS, it seems like some of the services are corrupted, re installing the system will be better.

Comment: I don't understand.... When I mean it can't shut down, it basically just removes the icons and taskbar, closes the windows and that's it.... The background remains there and the mouse pointer remains there too.... I can even move it, surely that has got to do with the OS?

Answer (score -1):

You should reboot you system in safe mode. Restart you computer and press <kbd>F8</kbd> key before Windows logo appears

And choose safe mode press <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key.

I think You get aero now. If you get aero you should re-install your Graphics driver.

Comment: Tried it, no, aero didn't come

Comment: don't sign off each of your posts with "Tahnsk" or other salutations. Please check [our help center](http://superuser.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Also, composition is _disabled_ under safe mode, there is no way Aero will be enabled under safe mode.